# Making a default property unaccessible?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

A `UITableViewCell` by default has a `textLabel` property. Now, I've subclassed `UITableViewCell`, and have set up my own text layout system that doesn't use `textLabel`. To reduce chance of error, I'd like to make the default property `textLabel` unavailable to the compiler (auto-complete), and that if I try to access it outside the class, the code will not compile.

Making the property readonly will still allow me to access and change the label's properties, so that won't work.

Is there any way to do this?

**Edit:**

So the closest I've gotten so far is redeclaring the property in my subclass and deprecating it:

```
@property (nonatomic) UILabel *textLabel NS_DEPRECATED_IOS(2_0, 3_0);
```

which currently gives me a warning if I try to access the property. But this doesn't completely hide it from the compiler, and it also gives me a warning "Availability does not match previous declaration".

Comment: `@property(strong, readonly) IBOutlet UILabel *textLabel;` in new compiler

Comment: @AnoopVaidya see comment to below's answer

Answer (score 5):

Ok, figured it out. You can use the `UNAVAILABLE_ATTRIBUTE` macro to accomplish this:

```
@property (nonatomic) UILabel *textLabel UNAVAILABLE_ATTRIBUTE;
```

and then doing `cell.textLabel` gives a compile error: `textLabel is unavailable`.

Answer (score 1):

Its readonly. You can access but not assign. See header file.

```
@property(nonatomic,readonly,retain) UILabel *textLabel
```

//Example

```
@interface myCell : UITableViewCell
{

}

@end

@implementation myCell

-(void)check
{
    //You can access
    UILabel *label = self.textLabel;

    //You canot assign
    self.textLabel = label;
}

@end
```

Comment: You're misunderstanding. I don't want the property textLabel to even appear to the compiler. Currently, you can still do self.textLabel.text = ...